# Mysql 'MATCH AGAINST' is not retrieving correct answer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table '**table1**'. And it has a record:

```
type    id  title            description                    keywords   hidden 
poll    12  Who is best     Poll for selecting best leader
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE   MATCH(`title`,`description`,`keywords`,`hidden`) AGAINST ('Who is best' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

While i executing the query, it return null result but no error

Whats wrong with this query? it should return  one existing record, right?

Is there any extra setting is needed for the table, while we use  'IN BOOLEAN MODE'

Answer (score 1):

Some common words are ignored. See the [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) list, which contains all three of your search words.

Also, words shorter than 4 chars are not indexed.

You can either accept this, or you can tweak the full text search by modifying the stopwrod list or changing the length limit for indexed words.

[How to modify the stopword list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541265/mysql-modify-stopword-list-for-fulltext-search)

[How to modify shortest/longest word length in a full text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

I also recommend reading [the manual on IN BOOLEAN MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: In addition, words less than 4 characters are automatically excluded.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, but here it is more than 4 characters

Comment: @Linto . . . "Who" and "is" are ignored.  "best" is a stop word.

Comment: @klas,Both +Who +is +best or "Who is best" are not  working.Acoording to you, the words in 'stopword' won't display ?

Comment: The stopwords are not included in the index, so they cannot be found. I have modified my answer with links on how to modify the way full text indexes are built.